# How to Delete data from Database upon closing the browser

Tags: java, sql, jsp, session, servlets

When a user logs in to my web app, I create a session:

```
session.setAttribute("SessionNumber","100");
```

And his username is added to a table named `ONLINE_USERS.`
Other Online users will be able to see him, they see all online users

When the user clicks on the log out button, I delete that row from the table, then I delete the session using:

```
session.invalidate();
```

But let's say the user existed the browser, his session will be gone, but the row will stay in the database as an online user, how to avoid this?

I'm using JSP-Servlets on Netbeans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable a custom `HttpSessionListener` to delete the table row upon session invalidation.

```
public class YourHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {       
   public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
   //put row in the database
   }

   public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
     //delete the row from database     
   }
}
```

Declare the listener in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>YourHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Note that there will be a delay between the moment the user exits the browser and his session expires on the server. But session expiration time is configurable. You should find a suitable expiration timeout: not too long so you don't display for too much offline users as online, but not too short to allow connected users an idle period.

I think this is a good trade off for a chat application developed with basic `servlet` and `jsp` technology.

Comment: It's okay if it's not instantly, but the delay can be more than 5 minutes? And where should I write those codes? I have index.jsp, chat.jsp, this is where the user spends his time, chatting.

Comment: The delay could be as long as the session expiration timeout you configured in web.xml (default 30 minutes). The `HttpSessionListener` is a standalone java class independent from any jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want see users that are operating on web site at the moment, problem with HttpSessionListener is that session can live quite long before its destroyed, so it can happen that the user is not using the web site long time when it is destroyed.
(see http://www.smartsoftwarebits.com/qaa/46-misc/82-how-to-set-session-timeout-for-tomcat )

**Solution**: You can add a column to the database where you will store the time stamp of the last request 
which user made. To keep this column up to date use a servlet filter. ( http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html )

To clear online users add a timer job (for example using quartz) where you will delete rows (online users) that are older than (for example) 5 minutes (thus when last interaction is older than 5 mins.) ( http://quartz-scheduler.org/ )

Using this you will now quite precisely if there is user is "still there" or not.

In addition you can add a timer to client side javascript to make an ajax call periodically. You can handle this way the situation when user did not close the browser just were inactive for a while.

Comment: This way you will wipe off valid sessions: users that didn't close their browsers but were inactive for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes, updated the answer with ajax call :)
But is also questionable, and depends on actual web site, if we want to handle inactive users as "online" or not

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to catch the event when the browser is closed

You can try below code snippet in your jsp to hit a js function which will call an ajax function to hit server side component. Then simply use the session API to invalidate the session and add the code to delete the record from the table.

```
window.onbeforeunload = WindowClose; 

function WindowClose() { 

  //Write a AJAx request here to hit the server side servlet  to invalidate the session

}
```

Or use

```
<body onunload="WindowClose(); >
```

In the server side code , use

HttpSession session = request.getsession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0); //or session.invalidate();

It will be good approach to define default session timeout value in the web.xml so that incase browser crashes, sessions will invalidate after the stipulated amount of time has passed.

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```